# Apache - vHost - Forbidden

Tags: apache, virtualhost, vhosts

I am trying to make a vhost that point "*:9090" to a specific directory. I'll explain.

That print below shows it's working the path i want.

[image]

So, I am trying to do "*:9090" point to this path (/wamp/www/root/dev). Below what i tried.

```
<VirtualHost *:9090>
DocumentRoot "c:/wamp/www/root/dev"

<Directory c:/wamp/www/root/dev>
    Options all
    Allow from all
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

And now, below, a print of my result.

[image]

What am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same issue until I used this:

```
<Virtualhost *:80 >
    ServerName site.domain.com
    DocumentRoot /path/to/site
    <Directory /path/to/site>
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
    </Directory>

    ServerAdmin user@domain.com

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</Virtualhost>
```

Comment: Don't get it...are you talking about ServerName??

Comment: You can probably just take that out or set it to localhost

Comment: Even after restarting WAMP?